# Version API in JAX-RS 2.0 / RESTeasy

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, resteasy

We want to version our REST API. The version is for the whole API and not for a single resource.

I thaught of having a javax.ws.rs.core.Application for every API version, which then referes to the resources it exposes.

```
- com.foo.bar.rest.v1
  - MyApiApplicationV1
    - MyResourceOne (Path: /api/one; X-VERSION: 1)
    - MyResourceTwo (Path: /api/two; X-VERSION: 1)
- com.foo.bar.rest.v2
    - MyApiApplicationV2
      - MyResourceOne (Path: /api/one; X-VERSION: 2)
      - MyResourceThree (Path: /api/three; X-VERSION: 2)
```

The Version of the API is passed in the X-Version header.

My question is: is it possible to activate MyApiApplicationV1 if the X-VERSION header is 1 and MyApiApplicationV2 if the X-Version header is 2? How to?

We're using JAX RS 2 / RESTeasy 3

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JAX-RS application is mapped to a path usually by web.xml configuration or by using [@ApplicationPath](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html). If the path identifies your application you can't have two applications running on the same path.

To workaround this you could add a third application or a simple servlet which redirects to the appropriate version depending on your version header.

**Unrelated:** Here's [a good talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/rest-misconceptions) about if and when versioning of RESTful APIs makes sense (starting at 00:26).

Comment: Thanks. Yes for now we're using ApplicationPaths /rest/1, /rest/2, etc. The mapping is done in the Enterprise Service Gateway. I just thaught of having a mapping possiblity in RESTeasy for local test without an ESG. So I'll go for the servlet/redirect approach.